# SQL Multiple meetings to one user and vice versa

Tags: c#

I'm creating a meeting program in c# using SQL. How would i go about adding multiple users from the user table to one meeting and vice versa (multiple meetings to one user from the table)

Sorry I'm new to SQL

SQL DB Format: User

```
[UserID]     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[FirstName]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[LastName]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Username]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Password]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Exc1]       BIT  NULL,
[Exc2]       BIT  NULL,
[Exc3]       BIT  NULL,
[Exc4]       BIT  NULL,
[Exc5]       BIT  NULL,
[Importance] INT          NOT NULL,
[Meetings]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [Meetings] FOREIGN KEY ([Meetings]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Meeting] ([MeetingID])
```

Meeting

```
[MeetingID] VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Title]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Date]      DATE          NOT NULL,
[StartTime] TIME (7)      NOT NULL,
[EndTime]   TIME (7)      NOT NULL,
[Location]  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Exc1]      BIT   NULL,
[Exc2]      BIT   NULL,
[Exc3]      BIT   NULL,
[Exc4]      BIT   NULL,
[Exc5]      BIT   NULL,
[Summary]   VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[UserID]    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MeetingID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [UserID] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is a n to n relation and you need an additional table like

```
usermeetings
[UsermeetingsID]
[UserID]
[MeetingID]
```

And you can remove the userid columns from meeting table and meetings columns from user table